# Passing Entity between activities (serializing)

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm working on Android app with Google App Engine JAVA backend.

I've got Entity object from app engine backend, and I need to pass it from one Activity to another in Android app. Puting it into bundle as serializable extra throws exception, most probably because my Entity class doesn't implements Serializable (and I guess it can't implement it).

What would be the proper way to serializing entities objects at client side, for bundle packing purposes?

Comment: Entity is a final class so you can not override it to make serializable or parcelable..so you have to maintain it as a static..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use **GSON** to do this.

Gson is a Java library that can be used to

```
1. Convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. 
2. And also Convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object.
```

Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Comment: it failed while converting back from json with gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyEntity.class) with some "wrong field" or something

Comment: Check with your JSON string..  Definitely something wrong with your JSON string alone

Comment: what could be possibly wrong with json string? it was created using gson.toJson(myEntity)

Comment: I had a problem where Gson failed because my object had a Date field. I managed to go around it by using GsonFactory and factory.toString and factory.fromString

Answer (score 0):

I found that Gson isn't all that reliable and it takes a lot to write the Adapter.  I went to EventBus for help and it works great!  :)